# How to use .each() or another method to change the color of the first point in a D3.js scatter plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I have a scatter plot which uses three different CSV's. The following is the Javascript that controls the dots used for one of them:

```
svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot")
    .data(files[2])
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.Index); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.Value); } )
      .attr("r", 4)
      .style("fill", "#d3d3d3")
```

Currently, the dots from this CSV are light grey. However, how could I make the first point listed in this CSV, or any other I want, a different color? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

In order to achieve what you want, you could use a callback in the `fill` style, just like you are doing in `cx` and `cy`, but adding a second parameter `i`, this callback's second parameter is the index (zero based), then you can conditionally return one value or another. Something like this:

```
svg.append('g')
  .selectAll("dot")
  .data(files[2])
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.Index); } )
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.Value); } )
    .attr("r", 4)
    .style("fill", function (d, i) { 
      if(i === 0) {
        return "#f05050"
      } else {
        return "#d3d3d3"
      }
    })
```